# Cannot find ... Permission Denied :( (Eclipse C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, permissions

I searched through various forums but I could not find any answer to my question.

Eclipse doesn't find my libraries even if they are there; I basically get

> Cannot find -lC:\Developpement\Workspace\PPmath\librairies\SDL2.dll

when they are clearly in that folder. I also get

> Cannot find -lC:\Developpement\Workspace\PPmath\librairies: permission
>   denied

**even if I open as administrator** and I don't understand why.

Comment: The `-l` compiler option is meant for libraries: `-lC:\Developpement\Workspace\PPmath\librairies\SDL2.lib`. Also check if you set the `-L` library paths correctly. And finally, you don't link against `.dll` directly, but use it's corresponding `.lib` stub.

Answer (score 2):

- You can add SDL2.dll to debug/ (which has [project_name].exe)
- Or you can add the path(which has sdl2.dll) as environment veriable.

I've been using eclipse for months, i don't know why but I always have your situation , always missing another dll.